# ajax: обмен данными между клиентом и сервером

Tags: jquery, ajax, клиент-сервер

У меня стоит задача реализации чата - нерегулярного обмена данными (сообщениями) между клиентом и сервером.

Реализовал следующим образом:

1) если текст отправляет клиент, отправка на сервер осуществляется мгновенно

```
$.ajax({
    url:        "server.php",
    type:       "POST",
    data:       {...},
});
```

2) по таймеру, регулярно (раз в 5 сек) запрашиваю у сервера через тот же `$.ajax`, появились ли новые сообщения, получаю их и обрабатываю

И решение проблем, таких как:

1) новый запрос на сервер не посылается, пока не получен ответ от предыдущего запроса и не прошло 5 сек

**Такой вопрос:**

Так и надо реализовывать или это неоптимальный путь и надо делать по другому?

Comment: Вы рассматривали возможность использования websocket-ов? Думаю, они бы ощутимо упростили жизнь.

Comment: вы реализовали самый простой вариант. Самый эффективный - это двухсторонний обмен данными, чтобы сервер уведомлял клиента когда приходят новые сообщения. Это можно делать веб сокетами, или библиотеками, которые используют веб сокеты (например, SignalR).

Comment: по 2 ответам понял, что нужны вебсокеты, у них никаких ограничений по современным браузерам нет?